# Place tab bar at top/or vertically right of the iPad

Tags: ipad, tabbar

Any help is appreciable

I am new to iOS. i need a tab bar to be placed at top or vertically right of the iPad.i am no t sure whether vertical tab bar in IOS.Is it possible to place tab bar at top.
Please help me with some sample codes

Comment: Its not possible to place a tabbar at top, because its not a standard approach. U can create a UIView with buttons and make it work like a tabbar if u want.

Answer (score 1):

Tab bar at the top isn't standard UI. If you want something at the top, use a UINavigationBar. Drag it in from interface builder if you don't know how to programmatically instatiate one.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give a try to this custom implementation of vertical tab bar: https://github.com/futuresimple/FSVerticalTabBarController It works similarly to the original UITabBarController but places the tab bar on the left side of screen.